# How to "Enable mobile data" on a Huawei E3372 4G USB dongle using a bash script in Windows

Tags: bash, curl, usb, 4g, dongle

!! **EDIT**: a solution can be found at the bottom of the question !!

I am using a Huawei E3372 4G USB dongle on Win8.1. This dongle's settings can be accessed via browser by typing 192.168.8.1 and the user can enable a 4G connection by manually clicking the "Enable mobile data" button.

This is the script I am trying to use to "Enable mobile data" connection, knowing I'm doing something wrong only on line 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s -X GET "http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/token" > token.xml
TOKEN=$(grep -v '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><token>' -v '</token></response>' token.xml)

curl "http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/mobile-dataswitch" -H "Host: 192.168.8.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Goanna/4.8 Firefox/68.0 PaleMoon/29.0.1" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;" -H "_ResponseSource: Broswer" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.8.1/html/content.html" -H "Cookie: SessionID=AgVjkIjBxOC0xPbys3nne7rA4I8GXNzUkZCcSOGPR8P3xss8XOuqRbdb0EgHidXhQXZ903xf0nk0F8J81ISqHpZ7kYvZaSW5wHWDqJ9w90pXj90cPwCm7F01fFcmp0gv" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-raw "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><request><dataswitch>1</dataswitch></request>"

date
exec $SHELL
```

Upon executing the first curl command, the xml file's content would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><token>ZsxY7Q9G90jh4FqUiAjxD9XmqLWf0rYg4RUNf6FoVzeTIlPPms0Ov1RERFFRY77o</token></response>
```

Just for test purposes, if I manually insert the token in the bash script, it works like a charm:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl "http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/mobile-dataswitch" -H "Host: 192.168.8.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Goanna/4.8 Firefox/68.0 PaleMoon/29.0.1" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;" -H "_ResponseSource: Broswer" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: ZsxY7Q9G90jh4FqUiAjxD9XmqLWf0rYg4RUNf6FoVzeTIlPPms0Ov1RERFFRY77o" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.8.1/html/content.html" -H "Cookie: SessionID=AgVjkIjBxOC0xPbys3nne7rA4I8GXNzUkZCcSOGPR8P3xss8XOuqRbdb0EgHidXhQXZ903xf0nk0F8J81ISqHpZ7kYvZaSW5wHWDqJ9w90pXj90cPwCm7F01fFcmp0gv" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-raw "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><request><dataswitch>1</dataswitch></request>"

date
exec $SHELL
```

I've found several suggestions for the same or similar dongles, none of them worked for me, it must be due to my insufficient knowledge. My cry for help is about line 4 of the top-most script. I am making a mistake somewhere obviously.

Thank you in advance for your help.

===== EDIT: SOLUTION IS FOUND ! =====

markp-fuso's suggestion was the path to my solution. Kudos. I just noticed that besides a variable "token" which was changing upon each "on/off" action, this dongle also had a less variable "SesTokInfo" which is not being changed upon each "on/off" action (I just tested that manually) and it is different than what it was yesterday. It could be "plug/unplug" of dongle that causes that, I honestly can't know.

To whom it may concern: The final form of the working script which I've just tested with positive result twice would be: (note that the script contains the curl command to "Enable mobile data". The one to "Disable mobile data" should contain 0 instead of 1 in the "dataswitch>1</dataswitch" part.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s -X GET "http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/token" > token.xml
curl -s -X GET "http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo" > sestoken.xml
TOKEN=$(sed -En 's|.*<token>(.*)</token>.*|\1|p' token.xml)
SESTOKEN=$(sed -En 's|.*<SesInfo>(.*)</SesInfo>.*|\1|p' sestoken.xml)
typeset -p TOKEN
typeset -p SESTOKEN

curl "http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/mobile-dataswitch" -H "Host: 192.168.8.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Goanna/4.8 Firefox/68.0 PaleMoon/29.0.1" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;" -H "_ResponseSource: Broswer" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.8.1/html/content.html" -H "Cookie: SessionID=$SESTOKEN" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-raw "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><request><dataswitch>1</dataswitch></request>"

date
exec $SHELL
```

Comment: please update the question with *a)* the output from `typeset -p TOKEN` and *b)* the results of the 2nd `curl` call (error? no output? wrong output? hangs?)

Comment: @markp-fuso I've edited my question dear markp-fuso, your suggestion was the path to the final solution, I verified it twice, and posted the final and working script at the end of the question. Bravo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your `grep -v ... -v ... token.xml` call I get an error:

```
$ grep -v '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><token>' -v '</token></response>' token.xml
grep: </token></response>: No such file or directory
```

After `TOKEN` has been populated I recommend you add `typeset -p TOKEN` (to show the contents of `TOKEN`); I'm guessing `TOKEN` does not contain what you think it does.

While xml should probably be parsed by a xml-capable tool, if you are 100% sure of the format of the contents in `token.xml` then the following should extract the token for you:

```
$ sed -En 's|.*<token>(.*)</token>.*|\1|p' token.xml
ZsxY7Q9G90jh4FqUiAjxD9XmqLWf0rYg4RUNf6FoVzeTIlPPms0Ov1RERFFRY77o
```

Then update your script with the following `TOKEN=$(...)` line:

```
$ TOKEN=$(sed -En 's|.*<token>(.*)</token>.*|\1|p' token.xml)
$ typeset -p TOKEN
declare -- TOKEN="ZsxY7Q9G90jh4FqUiAjxD9XmqLWf0rYg4RUNf6FoVzeTIlPPms0Ov1RERFFRY77o"
```